# JTable no aparece en el frame

Tags: java-swing, java-8, jtable

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class FacturacionGenericaApp extends JFrame {

    // Componentes Graficos
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FacturacionGenericaApp window = new FacturacionGenericaApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FacturacionGenericaApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1129, 519);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.cargarDatosDB();

        //create table with data
        JTable table = this.cargarTabla();
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);

    }

    private JTable cargarTabla() {   
        try {
            // The Connection is obtained
            Statement stmt = conexionDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt .executeQuery("select * from clientes");

            // It creates and displays the table
            return new JTable(construirModeloDeTabla(rs));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TableModel construirModeloDeTabla(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

}
```

El problema es que cuando inicia la aplicación no aparece la tabla:

[image: No aparece la tabla]

Pero si dentro de `cargarTabla()` pongo la siguiente línea:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se imprime en pantalla perfectamente! Por lo que la información se está cargando perfectamente, solo que no lo inserta en el frame.

¿Qué es lo que me estoy perdiendo?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Le asignas un `layout` **null** , por eso no agrega el componente, puedes asignar un `layout` _existen varios_  o eliminar esa línea y mostrará correctamente

Comment: Ahí la eliminé y apareció. Ese null en el layout se agregó porque apliqué un `absoluteLayout` para poder acomodar la tabla donde quiera, si lo borro entonces como puedo ubicar todo en la posición que quiera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción de **no usar** *Layout* para un *contenedor* es decir `.setLayout(null);` es que hay que especificar en que posición y el tamaño del elemento a añadir mediante el método [setBounds(x,y,ancho,alto)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds-int-int-int-int-)

```
 frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
 JTable table = this.cargarTabla();
 frame.add(table);
 table.setBounds (10,10,200,200);
```

> Aunque la recomendación es usar  [Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para administrar los
>   componentes en su contenedor

Comment: Mil gracias! Al final me decidí por la GridLayout! Te agradezco en serio